# How would I understand Hysteresis from scratch?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, elasticity, matter

I wanted to learn about [Hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) and I know the basic undergraduate level of 'Mechanical properties of matter".

Can anyone please help?

Comment: There are 10K hits for `"mechanical hysteresis"` on Google Scholar. [Early example.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0502820553900148) Please clarify what you're asking about.

Comment: He is asking what is it about a system that makes it have hysteresis? How does hysteresis work?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, hysteresis refers to a situation where the state of a system at a single moment in time cannot be determined only from the influences on it at that moment, but rather require a knowledge of its past states.

For example, you might start with a chunk of iron which has no average magnetization. If you apply a strong magnetic field to it, then it will become magnetized. If you take away the external field, then the iron will retain some permanent magnetization, and is therefore different from the chunk of iron you started with despite being in exactly the same environment.

For a more immediately down-to-Earth example, go find a water faucet. Turn it all the way off and then slowly turn the knob until water starts to flow. Take note of the position of the knob.  Now turn it all of the way on, and then slowly turn the knob back to the off position until water stops flowing. Take note of the position of the knob now.

Typically those two positions will not be the same. This is an example of hysteresis - for a certain set of knob positions, whether water is flowing depends not only on where the knob is, but also on whether the tap was just off or whether the tap was just on.

Comment: To understand why magnets have hysteresis, first see this video. [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM). If you put a magnet in a strong magnetic field, all the domains line up with the field and keep each other lined up when the field is turned off. If you point the field another direction, the domains would again line up with the field in the new direction, and stay lined up.

Comment: @mmesser314 Was this meant to be a comment on the OP?

Comment: @JMurray - Yes.